# Unique object counts are not getting counted in form of String but char

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List like below

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

Add(new Product { ProductId = "abc", Type = "Normal" });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "def",  Type = "Normal" });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "ghi",  Type = "VIP" });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "jkl",  Type = "Group" });

public Product Add(Product item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }
    products.Add(item);
    return item;
}
```

I want to count like:

```
Type: Normal Count: 2
Type: VIP Count: 1
Type: Group Count:1
```

I wrote below code

```
public string GetCount()
{
    int total = tickets.Count();
    string _text = "\nTotal " + total.ToString();
    var query = tickets.SelectMany(x => x.Type)
        .GroupBy(s => s)
        .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

    foreach (var result in query)
    {
        _text += " Type: " + result.Name +  " Count: " + result.Count;
    }

    return _text;
}
```

Output I am getting is

```
Type: N Count: 2
Type: o Count: 3
Type: r Count: 3
Type: m Count: 2
Type: a Count: 2
Type: l Count: 2
Type: V Count: 1
Type: I Count: 1
Type: P Count: 1
Type: G Count: 1
Type: u Count: 1
Type: p Count: 1
```

Not sure why Type is breaking into char and how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = products.GroupBy(x => x.Type)
                     .Select(g => string.Format("Type: {0} Count: {1}", 
                                                g.Key, 
                                                g.Count())
                                                );
string output = string.Join("\n", groups);
```

The reason your code didn't work is, `SelectMany` takes an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` and flattens it to `IEnumerable<T>`. Since `string` inplements `IEnumerable<char>`, `SelectMany` treats `IEnumerable<string>` as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>>` and the result is `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using ConsoleApplication3;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "abc", Type = "Normal" });
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "def", Type = "Normal" });
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "ghi", Type = "VIP" });
        products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "jkl", Type = "Group" });

        var result = from p in products
                     group p by p.Type into g
                     orderby g.Key
                     select new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Type: {0} Count: {1}", r.Key, r.Count));
        }

    }
}
```