# Unique object counts are showing system text

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List like below

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

Add(new Product { ProductId = "abc", Type = "Normal", Status = "1" });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "def",  Type = "Normal", Status = "2"  });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "ghi",  Type = "VIP" , Status = "1" });
Add(new Product { ProductId = "jkl",  Type = "Group", Status = "1" });

public Product Add(Product item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }
    products.Add(item);
    return item;
}
```

I want to count like:

Type: Normal Count: 2
Type: VIP Count: 1
Type: Group Count:1

from earlier help at below location
[Unique object counts are not getting counted in form of String but char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830445/c-sharp-list-unique-object-counts-are-not-getting-counted-in-form-of-string-but)

I wrote code

```
var groups = products.GroupBy(x => new { x.Type, x.Status }).Select(g => string.Format("Type: {0} Count: {1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
```

When I run above I get text in groups as below

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32],LocalServer.Product],System.String]##

Not sure how to fix, or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issues.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "abc", Type = "Normal", Status = "1" });
products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "def",  Type = "Normal", Status = "2"  });
products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "ghi",  Type = "VIP" , Status = "3" });
products.Add(new Product { ProductId = "jkl",  Type = "Group", Status = "1" });

IEnumerable<string> groupedProducts = products.GroupBy(product => product.Type)
                                              .Select(grouping => string.Format("Type: {0} Count: {1}", grouping.Key, grouping.Count())); 

foreach (var groupedProduct in groupedProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(groupedProduct);
}
```

The problem was that you were trying to group by a number of properties, since you only want to count by `Type`, use `.GroupBy(product => product.Type)`, then use the `.Select()` to project the results in any fashion you want.

Comment: There is another twist. I need to get the counts, which works thanks, plus I need to also count Status like in above example count status 2, which should show up like 1/2. Total Normal are 2, but one of them status is 1.

Comment: Can you write an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: Normal: 1/2
VIP: 0/3
Group: 0/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the group Key property's Type property to get the type name becouse you are grouping by a new annonymous type.

```
var groups = products.GroupBy(x => new { x.Type, x.Status }).Select(g => string.Format("Type: {0} Count: {1}", g.Key.Type, g.Count()));
```